# How to show Progress control or gif in android?

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-activity

When I call webservice on clicking button, it waits to load records on new activity and shows activity blank during that time period.

Can any one guide me how to show progress during that time period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could display a progress view on your activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
     private static final int PROGRESS = 0x1;

     private ProgressBar mProgress;

     private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

     protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
         super.onCreate(icicle);

         setContentView(R.layout.progressbar_activity);

         mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
         mProgress.setIndeterminate(true);
         mProgress.setVisibility(true);

         // Start lengthy operation in a background thread
         new Thread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 doWork();
                 mProgress.setVisibility(false);
             }
         }).start();
     }
 }
```

See [ProgressBar documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html).